# Sprite Kit - Detect contact

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have two Sprite Nodes:

```
-(void)createPlayer {
    SKSpriteNode *player = [SKSpriteNode node];

    player.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:enemy.size];
    player.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = playerCategory;
    player.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = enemyCategory;

    player.position = CGPointMake(100, 160);
    player.name = @"player";
    player.zPosition = 100;

    [self addChild:player];
}

-(void)createEnemy {
    SKSpriteNode *enemy = [SKSpriteNode node];

    enemy.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:enemy.size];
    enemy.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = enemyCategory;
    enemy.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = playerCategory;

    enemy.position = CGPointMake(300, 160);
    enemy.name = @"player";
    enemy.zPosition = 100;

    [self addChild:enemy];
}
```

And the following in MyScene.h

```
static const uint32_t playerCategory =  0x1 << 0;
static const uint32_t enemyCategory =  0x1 << 1;
```

How do I detect if they make contact, so I can add an action as a result of their contact?

Comment: And what's the problem?  Where do you have difficulty?

Comment: Just as I said in the post above. How do I detect if they make contact, so I can add an action as a result of their contact? So, if player makes contact with enemy, do whatever..

Comment: assign a contact delegate to your SKPhysicsWorld https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsWorld_Ref/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsWorld/contactDelegate then listen to contact delegate messages: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsContactDelegate_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/SKPhysicsContactDelegate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your collision detection need's Delegate Methods.

in your **MyScene.h** your code should look like this:

```
@interface MyScene : SKScene <SKPhysicsContactDelegate>
```

In your **MyScene.m** add this inside your **initWithSize**:

```
self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
```

Now you need to implement the delegate method **didBeginContact**:

```
- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
    uint32_t collision = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask);

    if (collision == (playerCategory | enemyCategory)) {
        // Do your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error for self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = YES; And when I change YES to self. The player object pushes the enemy off screen.. So it's a collision in stead of just contact I suppose.

Comment: my mistake to correct syntax is contactDelegate = self, if you don't want a collision set the physicsBody.collisionBitMask to 0 and if you need you can change the delegate method to didEndContact

Comment: That works! Thank you so much! All I'm still struggling with is getting the right physics body size for the sprite node. But I'll figure that out. Thanks again!

Comment: How can I calculate the collision force between two bodies?

Comment: You can use the velocity of each object to calculate that value like node.physicsBody.velocity this will help you http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/carcr.html